# nrecognized option "amqp" under "oro_message_queue.transport". Available option is "dbal"

Tags: symfony, orocommerce

```
ubuntu@admin[enter image description here][1]:~/orocommerce-application$ symfony console oro:install -vvv --sample-data=y --application-url=https://127.0.0.1:8000 --user-name=admin --user-email=admin@example.com --user-firstname=John --user-lastname=Doe --user-password=admin --organization-name=Oro --timeout=0 --symlink --env=prod -n
```

In ArrayNode.php line 322:

[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
Unrecognized option "amqp" under "oro_message_queue.transport". Available option is "dbal".

Exception trace:
at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/config/Definition/ArrayNode.php:322
Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ArrayNode->normalizeValue() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/config/Definition/BaseNode.php:410
Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\BaseNode->normalize() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/config/Definition/ArrayNode.php:287
Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ArrayNode->normalizeValue() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/config/Definition/BaseNode.php:410
Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\BaseNode->normalize() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/config/Definition/Processor.php:32
Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Processor->process() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/config/Definition/Processor.php:46
Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Processor->processConfiguration() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Extension/Extension.php:111
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Extension\Extension->processConfiguration() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/MessageQueueBundle/DependencyInjection/OroMessageQueueExtension.php:38
Oro\Bundle\MessageQueueBundle\DependencyInjection\OroMessageQueueExtension->load() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:76
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:42
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Compiler/Compiler.php:82
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php:757
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/DistributionBundle/OroKernel.php:407
Oro\Bundle\DistributionBundle\OroKernel->initializeContainer() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:789
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->preBoot() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:128
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/oro/platform/src/Oro/Bundle/DistributionBundle/OroKernel.php:231
Oro\Bundle\DistributionBundle\OroKernel->boot() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:168
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->registerCommands() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Console/Application.php:74
Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:171
Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/ubuntu/orocommerce-application/bin/console:33

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to set up the amqp transport in config/parameters.yml, which is not available in the community edition of OroCommerce.

You have reset the message queue configuration to the default value that you can find in the config/parameters.yml.dist and clear the cache to apply changes